# Dspace shows empty values in statistics

Tags: solr, repository, dspace

Dspace 6.3 shows no values in statistics. Moreover, it cannot browse authors. I guess, there are problems with solr, but I have no idea how to fix it. Here are solr logs:

```
2023-11-06 00:00:16,328 INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore @ [search] webapp=/solr path=/select params={q=handle:123456789/708&mlt=true&fl=handle,search.resourcetype,search.resourceid&mlt.fl=dc.title_mlt,dc.contributor.author_mlt,dc.creator_mlt,dc.subject_mlt&mlt.minwl=5&mlt.count=3&wt=javabin&version=2&mlt.mintf=5} hits=1 status=0 QTime=1
2023-11-06 00:00:24,339 INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore @ [search] webapp=/solr path=/select params={q=*:*&fl=handle,search.resourcetype,search.resourceid&start=0&fq=NOT(withdrawn:true)&fq=NOT(discoverable:false)&fq=search.resourcetype:2&fq=read:(g6a37bd50-ce39-490d-a99f-9f014d9ad733+OR+g6a37bd50-ce39-490d-a99f-9f014d9ad733)&wt=javabin&version=2} hits=1460 status=0 QTime=1
2023-11-06 00:00:24,347 INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore @ [search] webapp=/solr path=/select params={q=*:*&fl=handle,search.resourcetype,search.resourceid&start=303&fq=NOT(withdrawn:true)&fq=NOT(discoverable:false)&fq=search.resourcetype:2&fq=read:(g6a37bd50-ce39-490d-a99f-9f014d9ad733+OR+g6a37bd50-ce39-490d-a99f-9f014d9ad733)&sort=bi_sort_1_sort+asc&rows=20&wt=javabin&version=2} hits=1460 status=0 QTime=1
2023-11-06 00:00:49,214 INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore @ [search] webapp=/solr path=/select params={q=handle:123456789/1326&mlt=true&fl=handle,search.resourcetype,search.resourceid&mlt.fl=dc.title_mlt,dc.contributor.author_mlt,dc.creator_mlt,dc.subject_mlt&mlt.minwl=5&mlt.count=3&wt=javabin&version=2&mlt.mintf=5} hits=1 status=0 QTime=1
2023-11-06 00:00:54,271 INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore @ [search] webapp=/solr path=/select params={q=handle:123456789/1406&mlt=true&fl=handle,search.resourcetype,search.resourceid&mlt.fl=dc.title_mlt,dc.contributor.author_mlt,dc.creator_mlt,dc.subject_mlt&mlt.minwl=5&mlt.count=3&wt=javabin&version=2&mlt.mintf=5} hits=1 status=0 QTime=1
2023-11-06 00:00:58,593 INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore @ [search] webapp=/solr path=/select params={q=handle:123456789/2034&mlt=true&fl=handle,search.resourcetype,search.resourceid&mlt.fl=dc.title_mlt,dc.contributor.author_mlt,dc.creator_mlt,dc.subject_mlt&mlt.minwl=5&mlt.count=3&wt=javabin&version=2&mlt.mintf=5} hits=1 status=0 QTime=1
2023-11-06 00:01:06,796 INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore @ [search] webapp=/solr path=/select params={q=handle:123456789/806&mlt=true&fl=handle,search.resourcetype,search.resourceid&mlt.fl=dc.title_mlt,dc.contributor.author_mlt,dc.creator_mlt,dc.subject_mlt&mlt.minwl=5&mlt.count=3&wt=javabin&version=2&mlt.mintf=5} hits=1 status=0 QTime=1
2023-11-06 00:01:11,714 INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore @ [search] webapp=/solr path=/select params={q=handle:123456789/940&mlt=true&fl=handle,search.resourcetype,search.resourceid&mlt.fl=dc.title_mlt,dc.contributor.author_mlt,dc.creator_mlt,dc.subject_mlt&mlt.minwl=5&mlt.count=3&wt=javabin&version=2&mlt.mintf=5} hits=1 status=0 QTime=1
2023-11-06 00:01:41,580 INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore @ [search] webapp=/solr path=/select params={q=*:*&fl=handle,search.resourcetype,search.resourceid&start=0&fq=NOT(withdrawn:true)&fq=NOT(discoverable:false)&fq=location.coll:8de3d87e-e797-4694-a002-88a71daf31b8&fq=search.resourcetype:2&fq=read:(g6a37bd50-ce39-490d-a99f-9f014d9ad733+OR+g6a37bd50-ce39-490d-a99f-9f014d9ad733)&sort=bi_sort_3_sort+desc&rows=4&wt=javabin&version=2} hits=29 status=0 QTime=1
2023-11-06 00:01:45,519 INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore @ [search] webapp=/solr path=/select params={q=*:*&fl=handle,search.resourcetype,search.resourceid&start=0&fq=NOT(withdrawn:true)&fq=NOT(discoverable:false)&fq=location.coll:320a4e28-c485-4112-95b3-01e7f269d6a2&fq=search.resourcetype:2&fq=read:(g6a37bd50-ce39-490d-a99f-9f014d9ad733+OR+g6a37bd50-ce39-490d-a99f-9f014d9ad733)&sort=bi_sort_3_sort+desc&rows=4&wt=javabin&version=2} hits=9 status=0 QTime=1
2023-11-06 00:01:49,431 INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore @ [search] webapp=/solr path=/select params={q=*:*&fl=handle,search.resourcetype,search.resourceid&start=0&fq=NOT(withdrawn:true)&fq=NOT(discoverable:false)&fq=location.coll:97f86da1-3aaf-4c08-9336-047692897603&fq=search.resourcetype:2&fq=read:(g6a37bd50-ce39-490d-a99f-9f014d9ad733+OR+g6a37bd50-ce39-490d-a99f-9f014d9ad733)&sort=bi_sort_3_sort+desc&rows=4&wt=javabin&version=2} hits=15 status=0 QTime=1
```

I appreciate any help!